# Does the Canon EOS M5 provide focus confirmation for manual-focus lenses?

Tags: autofocus, canon-m

Suppose I were to mount an old, adapted, manual-focus-only lens on the Canon EOS M5. There would be no communication at all between the camera and the lens. As I adjusted the focus on the lens, would the camera’s autofocus system still show me which of the 45 AF points are activated? Would its focus peaking feature show me the “edges” of the focused object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I own a Rokinon EF-M 12mm f/2.0 wide angle lens, manual focus only, that I use with my EOS M3 and EOS M5. (To get the M5 to even recognize the lens, I had to change a "Custom Function" to allow the shutter to be released without a lens being detected. Look in the "C.Fn II: Others" section and change "Release shutter w/o lens" to "Enable".)

At this point, the MF Peaking feature will work fine with your manual-focus lens. However, the autofocus points will *not* light up like you describe.

Comment: I would like to know how you get this because I certainly dont. thanks Michel

Answer (score 2):

I just purchased both M5 and manual focus lens.
I don't believe the Canon M5 provides the feedback you are looking for.

I know exactly what you are asking for as I recall my Canon DSLR did beep and blink the focus point when I manually focused and I believe when I half pressed shutter.

Still experimenting with the Canon M5 but I don't see any configuration settings that would make this happen. The only relevant setting that is already mentioned is "Release shutter w/o lens" to "Enable". If this is not enabled, when you press the shutter button, nothing happens but does not provide any additional feedback during focus.

Comment: At least with my Canon EOS M5 and Rokinon EF-M 12mm f/2.0 wide angle lens, all of the points which are in focus glow a bright red when focus peaking is active. I just checked again, and that's the way it works, at least with my setup. Larry